# QGIS Action Open Image

Tags: qgis, actions

Can someone advise me where i might be going wrong when trying to open an Image in a Network folder using the Action function in QGIS

I have a point dataset with a column that has the image location on the Network. Network location is;

\gis\GIS\Environmental Health\Fly tipping\Images

A single record will therefore be \gis\GIS\Environmental Health\Fly tipping\Images\IMG_123.jpg

the action window is configured thus:
[image]

Using the Hotlink tool results in nothing opening

I've done this before with no problems and can also use a local drive location with no problems

I'm using QGIS 3.10 and Windows 10

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Did you try to mount the network e.g https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026635/windows-map-a-network-drive and then point your path to it? I'm not sure Windows network paths are working when trying to open resources

Comment: Hi yes, the drive is mapped, but i was using the full, non-mapped, path as this is easier to set up in the other software i am using to generate the point dataset (FME).

Comment: if `\gis\GIS\Environmental Health\Fly tipping\Images\IMG_123.jpg` mounted to `Z:\GIS\Environmental Health\Fly tipping\Images\IMG_123.jpg`, use `[%replace("Directory", '\\gis\\', 'Z:\\')   %]` Best of both world, opening with mounted path in QGIS, keeping the drive path unchanged because of your other constraints e.g FME